# Android sqlite jdbc can't connect because of Read-only file system

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to open an sqlite jdbc connection but I keep getting an exception

> java.sql.SQLException: opening db:
>   '\data\data\com.lppapp.ioi.lpp\databases\lppDB.db': Read-only file
>   system

Before trying to get the jdbc connection I copy the database into the internal storage and try to access it from there. I'm using this code to connect:

```
public Connection connect() {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:\\data\\data\\com.lppapp.ioi.lpp\\databases\\lppDB.db";
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.setProperty("open_mode", "1");
        //TODO: can't open db (read-only file system) even though directory has a+rw permissions
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, config);

        System.out.println("Connection successful.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection failed.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return conn;
}
```

I'm using an Android emulator and I've checked the permissions of the databases directory. [image]

I've tried every solution found on the web but with no help.

Comment: Why are you using JDBC, instead of Android's native SQLite API or things wrapped around it (e.g., Room)? Why are you using backslashes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've decided to use Android's native SQLite API as mentioned by CommonsWare.

Thanks!